# Wait for AWT repaint to finish

Tags: java, awt, frame

I have a `Frame` that is all one color, but has some text in the corner. I set the color, actually read the color from the monitor, and then do some computations based on those measurements.

The problem is, calling `repaint()` causes the `Frame` to be painted **after** I do the measurements. I'm assuming this is due to `repaint()` delegating to the EDT, but I'm getting incorrect results due to the measurements occurring before/during the actual painting work.

My initial thought was to put a listener on paint completion, but I repaint to update the text much more frequently than I do for the color and I don't want to listen to those events. How can I wait for the actual painting task to finish before taking my measurement?

Comment: You could synchronize threads around an anonymous lock object to make one thread wait for another.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't think you can (reliably). You could try using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)` to place your compulations onto the tail end of the EDT after you call repaint, but there is no guarantee that a repaint request has been placed on the EDT yet...

Comment: @Vulcan But I don't have any control over the EDT, do I? I suppose from a practical point of view, the EDT is probably FIFO, but from a correctness point of view, am I assured of that?

Comment: @MadProgrammer If the call to `repaint()` has finished, then don't I have a guarantee that it has been submitted to the EDT? Though we still have the (possible) issue of out-of-order execution on the EDT.

Comment: @AndyShulman No. Repaint requests may be consolidated in order to reduce the number of repaint events. *NOTE: If multiple calls to repaint() occur on a component before the initial repaint request is processed, the multiple requests may be collapsed into a single call to update(). The algorithm for determining when multiple requests should be collapsed is implementation-dependent. If multiple requests are collapsed, the resulting update rectangle will be equal to the union of the rectangles contained in the collapsed requests.*

Comment: @AndyShulman You may like to have a read of [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazing what you can find...

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {

                PaintEvent pe = (PaintEvent) event;

                String type = "";
                if (pe.getID() == PaintEvent.PAINT) {
                    type = "PAINT";
                } else if (pe.getID() == PaintEvent.PAINT_FIRST) {
                    type = "PAINT_FIRST";
                } else if (pe.getID() == PaintEvent.PAINT_LAST) {
                    type = "PAINT_LAST";
                } else if (pe.getID() == PaintEvent.UPDATE) {
                    type = "UPDATE";
                }

                System.out.println(type + "; pe.UpdateRec = " + pe.getUpdateRect() + "; pe.component = " + pe.getComponent());

            }
        }, AWTEvent.PAINT_EVENT_MASK);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }
});
```

Now, because repaint requests can come think and fast, I'd be tempted to place a small "delay" in that would fired shortly after the last request has completed...

```
private Timer updateTimer;

// ...

EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        updateTimer = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Update compulations here...
            }
        });
        updateTimer.setRepeats(false);
        updateTimer.setCoalesce(true);

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
                updateTimer.restart();
            }
        }, AWTEvent.PAINT_EVENT_MASK);
    }
}
```

The idea is to allow at least 250 milliseconds between the last repaint request and the start of your compilations.  You might like to play around with these values a bit and see what suits you...

**UPDATE**

You could also try [`JComponent.paintImmediately`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintImmediately%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

> Paints the specified region in this component and all of its
>   descendants that overlap the region, immediately.
>
> It's rarely necessary to call this method. In most cases it's more
>   efficient to call repaint, which defers the actual painting and can
>   collapse redundant requests into a single paint call. This method is
>   useful if one needs to update the display while the current event is
>   being dispatched.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do here -- but are you sure that they will get placed in the EDT in the correct order? Some testing showed that calling `repaint()` once produced 5 calls to my `paint()` method, and I don't know whether those were synchronous or tacked on to the end of the event queue.

Comment: Because it's possible for repaint requests to be consolidated, there is no guarantee that they will appear in the order you requested them.

Comment: I'm not sure how your solution will actually work, then. It seems to be revolving around "stick a delay in your code and hope for the best". Am I wrong?

Comment: Kind of. The point of the delay is so you don't respond to each paint event (as you could get dozens related to the same update request). The idea is to slide a small delay in to allow the EDT to go idle (or at least the requests for repaints in this case).  This is as close as I think you will get to "end of paint" cycle.  Unless you want to act with each paint event, but you'd need to test when you get notified of the event and when an actual paint call takes to place...

Comment: The other problem you have is that "repaint" isn't the only way paint requests are made. Java may be responding to requests from the OS, such as mouse over's, window movements and changes...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but in case someone is searching for an answer to this, [SwingUtilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) has a method called [invokeAndWait(Runnable)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait(java.lang.Runnable)) that runs the task on AWT dispatching thread synchronously with your current thread. Note that this cannot be done if you need it to be done inside the Event dispatching thread.